# Linux Shell script, kill as another user

Tags: linux, tcl, expect, bin

Recently I've been trying to get this script working:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set pssword [lrange $argv 0 0]
spawn su - kod -c cd cod4 -c "nohup kill 7938"  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
expect "Password:" { send "$pssword\r" }
expect "# " { send "q" }
exit
```

It should login as user called "kod" and kill the process by certain pid

Here is the starting script and it works just fine...

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set pssword [lrange $argv 0 0]
set port [lrange $argv 1 1]
set mod [lrange $argv 2 2]
set map [lrange $argv 3 3]
set num [lrange $argv 4 4]
set hostname [lrange $argv 5 5]
set rcon [lrange $argv 6 6]
set password [lrange $argv 7 7]
spawn su - kod -c cd cod4 -c "nohup ./cod4_lnxded +set s_num=$num +set net_port $port +set dedicated 2 +set fs_game mods/$mod +set sv_punkbuster 1 +set sv_hostname $hostname +set rcon_password $rcon +set g_password $password +set promod_mode match_mr10 +set g_gametype sd +map $map"  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
expect "Password:" { send "$pssword\r" }
expect "# " { send "q" }
exit
```

Please don't tell me to "login as root" or either "just use sudo" because that's not the case...
Thanks !

Comment: Why `nohup kill`? The `kill` command is quick.

Comment: Also, use `[lindex $argv 0]` instead of `[lrange $argv 0 0]` (unless you really want that extra list quoting, which you probably don't if your passwords contain list-significant characters!)

Answer (score 0):

I think the user who ran the process and the user that wanted to kill it should be in a common group. The process permission should be associated with that group too.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that your code is dropping any error messages that might be coming out of that (rather complex) command; it would be far better if you were to either print that information out immediately or log it to a file. Like that, you can diagnose problems rather than having to take wild guesses…

There are other problems too.

- You wrap the `kill` with `nohup`, but that's truly unnecessary as sending a signal is almost instantaneous and you don't want the extra complexities.
- You're passing passwords as command line arguments. That's insecure because *any* process can read the entire command line passed to any program. It's better to pull the password from a file that is named on the command line; then only you (and root) can read the password (which is OK) if you set the permissions right.
- You use `lrange` when extracting command line arguments; that's… almost certainly wrong (the `lindex` command is a better choice, or possibly even `lassign` to extract many values at once, provided it's running in Tcl 8.5 or later).
- You're hard-coding the process ID. That's almost certainly not what you want to do, as it's totally likely to be different over time.

Sorting through that little lot, I get this possible improved script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# A more robust method for handling arguments than you had...
if {$argc == 0} {
    error "usage: $argv0 pid ?passFile?"
}
set pid [lindex $argv 0]
if {$argc > 1} {
    set passwordFile [lindex $argv 1]
} else {
    # Sensible default
    set passwordFile ~/.codPassword
}

# Read the password from the file
set f [open $passwordFile]
gets $f pssword
close $f

# Run the program (doesn't need the 'cd') with trap to supply password,
# and connect to user for error passthrough
spawn su - kod -c kill $pid
expect_background {
    "Password:" {exp_send "$pssword\r"}
}
interact {eof close}
```

---

Thinking about this further, a long time after the question was posed, the other problem is this:

```
spawn su - kod -c cd cod4 -c "nohup kill 7938"  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

That's extremely likely to be doing something strange and unexpected. Instead, you probably need this:

```
spawn su -c "cd cod4; nohup kill 7938 > /dev/null 2>&1 &" - kod
```

That's because you want to pass all that lot as a single shell script to run inside the shell that `su` runs.